# how to add multiple targets in serverless.yml schedule event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to call multiple lambda from Cloudwatch event , I am not sure how to add other target lambda using serverless.yml. 
below code add only add one target but I want multiple , from console I can add multiple targets where I triggered different Lambda

```
 - schedule:
          name: lambda-warmer-scheduler
          description: 'scheduler to warmup lambdas '
          rate: rate(2 minutes)
```

From Console I can add multiple targets , how can we do it using yml
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
I now understand that your goal is to create a lambda warming system.
You can use the very good [serverless-plugin-warmup](https://github.com/FidelLimited/serverless-plugin-warmup) for this. It does exactly what you are trying to achieve, in the way you are trying to do it.

---

The events property in your function's declaration in serverless.yml is a list. You can add several events that will trigger your lambda:

```
functions:
  yourFunction:
    handler: yourFunction.handler
      events:
        - schedule:
              name: lambda-warmer-scheduler
              description: 'scheduler to warmup lambdas '
              rate: rate(2 minutes)
        - schedule:
              name: lambda-warmer-scheduler-2
              description: 'scheduler to warmup lambdas '
              rate: rate(5 minutes)
        - schedule:
              name: lambda-warmer-scheduler-3
              description: 'scheduler to warmup lambdas '
              rate: rate(5 hours)
```

Each item on the events property will create an event (in this example only schedules but you can mix different event sources, like schedules, http, streams...).

Comment: but it will create another scheduler , I want one scheduler and multiple targets. My Scenario is I have one Order Lambda that will call other Lambda SecurityLamba> ProductLambda. So I want to warmup all lambda from one Lambda that is Order in my case. Otherwise I can create scheduler in every lambda.

Comment: I edited my answer with a link to a serverless plugin which does EXACTLY what you want to achieve. I use it in all my projects.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, yes I am looking for warmup lambda, I am new to serverless world can you give me idea how can I add plugin , I am using .net core project. not sure where to execute npm , (Install via npm in the root of your Serverless service)  where is root of serverless service.

Comment: The root of the serverless service is where your serverless.yml file is.